# Scala class that creates an instance of another class

Tags: scala, class, oop, inheritance

I have a matrix class defined as follows:

```
class Matrix(private val A: Array[Array[Double]]){...}
```

I would like to create a vector class, and since vectors are matrices, it would make sense for a vector object to just be a matrix object. However, I would like to construct vector objects by passing an `Array[Double]` as a parameter, and not an `Array[Array[Double]]`.

Essentially, I would like a wrapper for my matrix class that takes an `Array[Double]` as a parameter - e.g. `Array(1,2)` - and creates the appropriate matrix - so in this case `Matrix(Array(Array(1),Array(2))`

Something like:

```
class Vec(array: Array[Double]){
    private val size = array.size
    private val arrayAsMatrix: Array[Array[Double]] = Array.ofDim[Double](size, 1)
    for(i <- 0 until n) matrix(i) = Array(array(i))
    //create a Matrix(arrayAsMatrix)
}
```

I would then like to use all of the matrix functions I have defined in `Matrix` (addition, multiplication, etc.) as normal - and perhaps add some new methods to `Vec` such as a `norm`.

I'm quite new to Scala so haven't really made any progress with this so far at all.

Answer (score 2):

In Scala I would first try to write an extension class (I think they are called "type class") to treat arrays like vectors and matrices instead of trying to force the API into object oriented space. They are zero-cost abstraction (compiler understands it well).

```scala
object LinearAlgebra {
  implicit class VectorOps(val self: Array[Double]) extends AnyVal {
    def rank = ???
    ???
  }

  implicit class MatrixOps(val self: Array[Array[T]]) extends AnyVal {
    def rank = ???
    ???
  }
}
```

Then you can write code like:

```scala
import LinearAlgebra._
val vector = Array(1,2,3,4)
// this will effectively be "new VectorOps(vector).rank"
// but the compiler will optimize the temp object allocation out
println(vector.rank)
```

If done this way, many incorrect things will become compile time syntax error. Which would not be the case with object oriented design.

Comment: Extension class *are not* typeclass, and extension is not most idiomatic/first try that would be done in Scala

Comment: Are you intending to keep to yourself what IS the most idiomatic way in your opinion? That would be then the most idiomatic way to answer a Scala question on SO! :-D